# controlling fields nullability in spark-sql and dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark-sql's DataFrame to implement a generic data integration component.
basic idea, user configures fields by naming them and mapping them with simple sql fragments (ones that can appear in the select clause), the component adds this columns and group them in struct fields (using [struct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#struct(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) from the columns DSL).

later processing takes some of this struct fields and group them into an array, at this point I hit an issue related to one of the fields being nullable in one tuple and not nullable in the other.

since the fields are grouped in a struct I was able to extract the struct type, modify it and use the *Column.cast* method to apply it back to the entire tuple, I'm not sure if this approach would work for top level fields (btw, the SQL cast syntax doesn't allow specifying fields' nullability).

my question is, is there a better way to achieve this? something like a *nullable()* function that can be applied to an expression in order to tag it as nullable, similar to the way cast works.

Sample code:

```
val df = (1 to 8).map(x => (x,x+1)).toDF("x","y")
val df6 = df.select(
      functions.struct( $"x" + 1 as "x1", $"y" + 1 as "y1" ) as "struct1",
      functions.struct( $"x" + 1 as "x1", functions.lit(null).cast( DataTypes.IntegerType ) as "y1" ) as "struct2"
    )
val df7 = df6.select( functions.array($"struct1", $"struct2") as "arr" )
```

this fails with this exception:

> cannot resolve 'array(struct1,struct2)' due to data type mismatch:
>   input to function array should all be the same type, but it's
>   [struct, struct];
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve
>   'array(struct1,struct2)' due to data type mismatch: input to function
>   array should all be the same type, but it's [struct,
>   struct];

and the fix looks like this:

```
//val df7 = df6.select( functions.array($"struct1", $"struct2") as "arr" )
val df7 = df6.select( functions.array($"struct1"  cast df6.schema("struct2").dataType, $"struct2" ) as "arr" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a little cleaner with a `udf` that creates an `Option[Int]`:

```
val optionInt = udf[Option[Int],Int](i => Option(i))
```

Then you need to use `optionInt($"y" + 1)` when you create `y1` for `struct1`. Everything else stays the same (although edited for conciseness).

```
val df6 = df.select(
  struct($"x" + 1 as "x1", optionInt($"y" + 1) as "y1" ) as "struct1",
  struct($"x" + 1 as "x1", lit(null).cast(IntegerType) as "y1" ) as "struct2"
)
```

Then `df6.select(array($"struct1", $"struct2") as "arr" )` works fine.

Comment: that'd probably work but it has few deficiencies first it requires the hustle of defining the udf, then it has to be defined for all types used, and another thing is that Catalyst has no idea what's going on inside the udf which might mean some loss of optimization opportunities.